# Path of image gets changed to localhost, even on production server, in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

### Problem

I uploaded an image using the inbuilt tool and added it to a blog post.  All this on the production server, across the pond in Montana, US.

It displays fine (using the correct absolute path it should: "/Media/Default/BlogPost/...") in the preview of the blog post.  But once I publish it, I get a broken image in the live site.  The reason being that the path renders as:

http://localhost:[port number]/Media/Default/BlogPost/...

Obviously, if running on a Dev machine, this will still work, but once on the live web server, this no longer works.

### History

I downloaded WebMatrix onto my machine, downloaded orchard, installed the Minty theme, made a new theme that uses Minty as the BaseTheme.  Then, once everything was almost there, uploaded onto the live web server.

I can't see how this can affect how the server interprets an absolute path, but maybe I am missing something?

### Fudged solution

I can fudge a solution by using the URL of the site i.e. I open the image picker and in the URL for the image resource text box I put:

http://blogs.mysite.co.uk/Media/Default/BlogPost/...

With this full URL, the problem goes away, but it is a fudge and I shouldn't need to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a reliable repro, you should file a bug.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  I have filed a bug on the orchard site, and set up a post to display the issue.

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy:  The issue was caused by the Vanderlay Relative URL Filter.  Shouldn't there be a warning on the module author's site?

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy:  A warning saying that dumb newbies might find that their images won't display properly if they have the Vanderlay Relative URL Filter enabled.  But never mind, all is well that ends well.

Comment: @awrigley I ran into this same issue and found an alternate solution is to go into the Site Settings and change the "Base URL" from the localhost to the live URL (http://www.mysite.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gelistir from the Orchard discussion pages answered this.

It is caused by a module, the Vanderlay Relative URL Filter module.  Disabling the module (that I wasn't using anyway, not even sure what it does...) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever this is worth, more than 2 years have passed since the question was asked. Anyway, if the problem described here happens to you, on the dashboard go into Settings and under "General", set your base url to your "http://www.yourdomain.com", instead of to "http://localhost[portnumber]". This is where the Vanderlay module gets the url to rewrite from.

Regards,